# If there are two bonds in connected graph $G$ with $e$ in their intersection, there is a bond $C$ in their union, minus element $e$

Tags: graph-theory

Sorry for the terrible title, found it hard to write with the letter limit. Any edit would be appreciated!

Let $A,B$ be bonds of connected graph $G$. Let $e \in A \cap B$. Show that there is a bond $C$, so that $C \subseteq (A \cup B) \setminus \{e\}$

A **bond** is a minimal (but not necessarily minimum), nonempty set of edges whose removal disconnects a graph. In this case, refer to a bond as a set of edges whose removal turns a connected graph to a a **graph with 2 connectivity components**.

Any hints on how to prove this would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is the statement even true? It seems to me that if $G$ is a complete graph of three vertices and $A$ and $B$ are two different pairs of edges, then $A\cap B$ is a singleton and its removal doesn't even disconnect $G$.

Comment: oops! Should be the union of course. Fixed!

Comment: So the thing you want to show is that $(A\cup B)\setminus\{e\}$ disconnects $G$, right? It seems that a set of edges contains a bond if and only if it disconnects.

Answer (score 0):

I've been wrangling with this question and think I may have the key to a solution:

You know that A and B are not disjoint.  Thus A∪B, which is an edge cut, must contain two distinct (i.e not A or B) disjoint bonds since we know that every edge cut is the disjoint union of bonds.

Thus (A∪B)∖{e} must contain one of these other bonds since e can belong to at most one of them.